# Does POSIX specify sed -E?

Tags: sed, posix, portability, standard

`sed` uses basic regular expressions (BRE) by default. Some implementations offer an option to switch to extended regular expressions instead.

GNU sed introduced the `-r` option to do so in version 3.01 from 1998 (see [research](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666147/187122)). Later, in version 4.2 from 2009, `-E` was added as an undocumented synonym for `-r` to be compatible with BSD implementations. The synonym was first documented in 2013 (see [commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/?id=v4.2.2-9-g8b65e07)) and then released in version 4.3 from 2017.

**Since then GNU sed claims `-E` to be POSIX.**

From `man sed` and `sed --help`

> -E, -r, --regexp-extended
> use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX -E).

From the [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options)

> the -E extension has since been added to the POSIX standard (http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so use -E for portability

And from the [commit message](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/?id=v4.2.2-9-g8b65e07) that introduced these claims

> "-E" is now in POSIX. See: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528

However, **I cannot find `sed -E` in any POSIX standard.** In the [latest version](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) I could find, the only documented options were `-e`, `-f`, and `-n`.

> The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition
> IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 (Revision of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008)
> Copyright © 2001-2018 IEEE and The Open Group
>
> NAME
> sed - stream editor
>
> SYNOPSIS
> sed [-n] script [file...]
> sed [-n] -e script [-e script]... [-f script_file]... [file...]
> sed [-n] [-e script]... -f script_file [-f script_file]... [file...]

**Question:**

- Is `sed -E` actually specified by POSIX?
- If yes, in which version and where can I read it?
- If not, how come these claims survived for 8 years and 9 versions of GNU sed?